# Populating ASP.NET Menu from both sitemap and database

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, dynamic-data, sitemap

I'm currently using a sitemap as a datasource for my ASP.NET Menu control, however I have one dropdown in the menu that I would like to be dynamically populated from a database. Does anyone know if this would be possible? I haven't been able to find anything online about using both a sitemap and a database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You would need to build your own sitemap provider to mix the two. Look here for a good artivle on building your own.

http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/articles/52749.aspx

You would need a slightly different approach where you let most of the default behaviour occur and then patched in your database driven data.